# Empirical bayes estimation of variograms for multiple variables

Tags: variogram, empirical-bayes

I am looking to estimate variograms, or spatial correlation matrices on all columns of a data matrix $\mathbf{X}_{n\times p}$ with $p>n$. The matrix of spatial coordinates $\mathbf{Y}_{n\times 2}$ is common to all variables. Because $n$ is so low, I am having trouble estimating separate variograms for each variable j=1,...,p, and would like to stabilize the estimates by sharing information between features. I know that there must be some common spatial structure to all features. Does there exist any empirical Bayes procedures for shrinking variograms towards some prior estimated from the data? The variograms can be estimated in any way (parametric or not), but the final estimate needs to be a positive-definite correlation matrix. I am not interested in quantifying variability of the final estimates, I only want to reduce this variability for downstream used. Neither am I interested in spatial interpolation like empirical Bayes kriging.

I have tried Tweedie's formula on the parameters of some parametrically estimated variogram, but this failed due to inaccurate and correlated parameter estimates, as well as the non-linear relationship between nugget and range parameters and the final covariances.

Comment: Which information specifically do you wish to have common to all features?  Variograms are often parameterized in terms of a nugget, an optional measurement variance, and a positive linear combination of a finite number of well-known functions (spherical, exponential, etc.) each parameterized by a range and sill.  Depending on which parameters you want to be common among the variables (e.g., range and functional form), maximum likelihood methods might be readily adaptable.

Comment: @whuber. Thanks for your answer. The variograms do no need to follow any parametric form, but if they do, then I want shrinkage on both nugget and range. I have indeed also fitted the model with a single common value for nugget and range using ML but I want something in between: less biased than assuming a common set of parameters (which is probably not true), but less variable than estimating unique MLE's for each feature separately, based on small $n$